# Ansible - how do I set directory permissions

Tags: linux, directory, permissions, ansible, yaml

I can't seem to find a way to change the permissions of a directory (not a file) in Ansible. There are plenty of docs and examples about file permissions, or directory creation, but I'm not finding any about changing directory permissions of an existing directory.

I've tried the method of "creating" a directory of the same path, including the permissions I want (0755), but I get an error about it thinking the directory is a file. "/path/to/dir already exists as a file"

```
-  name: "Change directory permissions"
     file:
       path: "{{ home_path }}/path/to/dir"
       state: directory
       mode: 0755
       owner: "{{ acct_id }}"
       group: "{{ acct_group }}"
```

I expected the directory permissions to change from  to 0755.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a file this task won't work for obvious reasons. Delete the file, run it again.

Comment: I just need to learn to read more clearly. The file was in a directory of the same name of the file, so I mixed the two up thinking the directory was what needed to  be changed. All good now. Thanks.